# How to handle the set the timezone to MST in Spring batch application that runs in AKS which follows UTC?

Tags: spring, datetime, timezone, spring-batch, azure-aks

I have a Spring batch application running in a VM hosted in MTC timezone. I am migrating this application to AKS which follows UTC.

I want to set MTC as my default timezone due to the business logic.

I could see the below options

1. Update the individual line of code to convert the UTC to MTC - not an efficient way.
2. Set the Default timezone - **How to do this in spring batch**? I could see this for spring boot but not for spring batch
3. Set Timezone at Container level (https://medium.com/@yildirimabdrhm/kubernetes-timezone-management-8cc139b01f9d)

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using

> java -Duser.timezone=America/Denver